# Want program to send ONE email at the end of program with all the data

Tags: python, loops, email, while-loop, html-email

So I have a code I made that makes it so it checks the weather for you etc.
I have it also so it sends you an email (if you want it to) with the data for your weather search.

BUT, it only sends the last search you did, not all the searches.

I have no idea how I would go about getting the code to gather all the data within the loop and THEN send the email with all answers and searches. The code here is just the normal code I have, not with a try for it to gather all data and then send it, I really dont know how I would make it do that :p

```
# - Good Morning Program -

#Import
import datetime
import requests
import sys
import smtplib
import ad_pw
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Input
name_of_user = input("What is your name?: ")

#Email
sender_email = ad_pw.email_address
password = ad_pw.email_password
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email, password)

#Loop
while True:

    #Input
    city = input('City Name: ')

    # API
    api_address='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=0c42f7f6b53b244c78a418f4f181282a&q='
    url = api_address + city
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()

    # Variables
    format_add = json_data['main']['temp']
    day_of_month = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d "))
    month = datetime.date.today().strftime("%b ")
    year = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y "))
    time = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    degrees = format_add - 273.15
    humidity = json_data['main']['humidity']
    latitude = json_data['coord']['lon']
    longitude = json_data['coord']['lat']

    #Program
    if degrees < 20 and time > str(12.00):
        print("\nGood afternoon " + name_of_user + ".")
        print("\nThe date today is: " +
              day_of_month +
              month +
              year)
        print("The current time is: " + time)
        print("The humidity is: " + str(humidity) + '%')
        print("Latitude and longitude for " + city + " is: " + str(latitude), str(longitude))
        print("The temperature is a mild " + "{:.1f}".format(degrees) +
              "°C, you might need a jacket.")

    elif degrees < 20 and time < str(12.00):
        print("\nGood morning " + name_of_user + ".")
        print("\nThe date today is: " +
              day_of_month +
              month +
              year)
        print("The current time is: " + time)
        print("The humidity is: " + str(humidity) + '%')
        print("Latitude and longitude for " + city + " is: " + str(latitude), str(longitude))
        print("The temperature is a mild " + "{:.1f}".format(degrees) +
              "°C, you might need a jacket.")

    elif degrees >= 20 and time > str(12.00):
        print("\nGood afternoon " + name_of_user + ".")
        print("\nThe date today is: " +
              day_of_month +
              month +
              year)
        print("The current time is: " + time)
        print("The humidity is: " + str(humidity) + '%')
        print("Latitude and longitude for " + city + " is: " + str(latitude), str(longitude))
        print("The temperature is a warm " + "{:.1f}".format(degrees) +
              "°C, don't forget to drink water.")

    elif degrees >= 20 and time < str(12.00):
        print("\nGood morning " + name_of_user + ".")
        print("\nThe date today is: " +
              day_of_month +
              month +
              year)
        print("The current time is: " + time)
        print("The humidity is: " + str(humidity) + '%')
        print("Latitude and longitude for " + city + " is: " + str(latitude), str(longitude))
        print("The temperature is a warm " + "{:.1f}".format(degrees) +
              "°C, don't forget to drink water.")

    restart = input('Would you like to check another city (y/n)?: ')
    if restart == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        # HTML
        html_message = """\
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <p>Hi, """ + str(name_of_user) + """<br>
            Here is the data from your weather search:<br>
            <br>
            City: """ + str(city) + """<br>
            Temperature: """ + "{:.1f}".format(degrees) + """°C<br>
             Humidity: """ + str(humidity) + """%<b>
            </p>
          </body>
        </html>
        """

        # Email
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg = MIMEText(html_message, "html")
        receive_email = input("Do you want to receive a copy from you search (y/n)?: ")
        if receive_email == 'y':
            receiver_email = input("Your e-mail: ")
            msg['From'] = sender_email
            msg['To'] = receiver_email
            print(
            'Goodbye, an email has been sent to ' + receiver_email + " and you will receive a copy for data from your searched cities there")
            server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print('Goodbye')
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: I will not dig in your code but if you need more than one item then you have to keep them on list.

Comment: you have almost the same code in every `if/elif/else` - you could put this in function to have this code only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send many items you have to keep them on list

```
results = []

while True:

    results.append({
        'city': city,
        'degrees': degrees,
        'humidity': humidity
    })
```

And then you can add it to message

```
for item in results:

    html_message += """City: {}<br>
    Temperature: {:.1f}°C<br>
     Humidity: {}%<b>
    """.format(item['city'], item['degrees'], item['humidity'])
```

---

Full working code with other changes

```
import datetime
import requests
import sys
import smtplib
import ad_pw
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_mail(name_of_user, receiver_email, results):
        # HTML
        html_message = """\
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <p>Hi, {}<br>
            Here is the data from your weather search:<br>
            <br>
        """.format(name_of_user)

        #---

        for item in results:

            html_message += """City: {}<br>
            Temperature: {:.1f}°C<br>
             Humidity: {}%<b>
            """.format(item['city'], item['degrees'], item['humidity'])

        #---

        html_message += "</p>\n</body>\n</html>"

        #---

        print(html_message)

        # Email
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg = MIMEText(html_message, "html")

        sender_email = ad_pw.email_address

        msg['From'] = sender_email
        msg['To'] = receiver_email

        #Email
        password = ad_pw.email_password
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender_email, password)

        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())


def display(text_1='afternoon', text_2='you might need a jacket'):
    print("\nGood {} {}.".format(text_1, name_of_user))
    print("\nThe date today is: {}".format(date))
    print("The current time is: {}".format(time))
    print("The humidity is: {}%".format(humidity))
    print("Latitude and longitude for {} is {},{}".format(city, latitude, longitude))
    print("The temperature is a mild {:.1f}°C, {}.".format(degrees, text_2))

# --- main ---

#Input
name_of_user = input("What is your name?: ")

results = []

#Loop
while True:

    #Input
    city = input('City Name: ')

    # API
    api_address='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=0c42f7f6b53b244c78a418f4f181282a&q='
    url = api_address + city
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()

    # Variables
    format_add = json_data['main']['temp']
    date = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y"))
    time = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    degrees = format_add - 273.15
    humidity = json_data['main']['humidity']
    latitude = json_data['coord']['lon']
    longitude = json_data['coord']['lat']

    results.append({
        'city': city,
        'degrees': degrees,
        'humidity': humidity
    })

    #Program
    if time > '12.00':
        text_1 = 'afternoon'
    else:
        text_1 = 'morning'

    if degrees < 20:
        text_2 = 'you might need a jacket'
    else:
        text_2 = "don't forget to drink water."

    display(text_1, text_2)

    restart = input('Would you like to check another city (y/n)?: ')
    if restart.lower().strip() != 'y':
        receive_email = input("Do you want to receive a copy from you search (y/n)?: ")
        if receive_email.lower().strip() == 'y':
            receiver_email = input("Your e-mail: ")
            send_mail(name_of_user, receiver_email, results)
            print('Goodbye, an email has been sent to {}\
and you will receive a copy for data from your searched cities there'.format(receiver_email))
        else:
            print('Goodbye')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Wow thanks, works like a charm! :)
I really need to re-read the list chapter